# Google Spreadsheets: Any Regex Replace

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, google-docs

I currently use

```
SUBSTITUTE(text, search_text, new text, occurrence)
```

to replace text, but I am starting to find that I have a list of things to replace, the above method will become something like

```
SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(...)...)...)...
```

very messy, whats a better method of making this work?

Answer (score 3):

You might be able to use a regular expression using the `REGEXREPLACE(text, regular_expression, replacement)` function instead.

If this doesn't work, it's possible to write custom functions using Google Apps Script. Maybe you could write one that can accept multiple strings to be replaced.

Edit: I just wrote such a function:

```
function SubstituteAll(text) {
  arguments = Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments);
  arguments.shift();
  var replacement = arguments.pop();
  for(var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++)
  {
    text = text.replace(arguments[i], replacement);
  }
  return text;
}
```

Usage:

```
SubstituteAll(text, search_text1, search_text2, ..., replacement_text)
```

Comment: How can I write that script? `Insert > Function > More ...` doesn't seem to be the right place, `Inset > Script ...` seems to provide publicly available scripts, where do I place my own? And I guess its using normal JS?

Comment: Use `Tools > Scripts > Script Editor`. Paste the code in, and save it under any name (I don't think it matters what you name it). Then you should to be able to use it like you would use any built-in function. [Example Spreadsheet](https://spreadsheets.google.com/ccc?key=0ArMBYT02_ES4dFEyX2c0YWhiTURWM3JFNlZHU2dkWmc&hl=en&authkey=CL_c27QI)

Comment: Docs just changed their menus, it's now in `Tools > Script Editor`.